# There is an address that is hacked, the bot is monitoring it and payments are received regularly!

Tags: go-ethereum, erc-20, geth-debugging, console

So, the bot instantly cancels these payments by sending, for example, 0.01 eth with a commission (fee) of 0.009 to another wallet, or even canceling everything through self - sending 0 to the same address, with a fee of 0.01!

In addition, the address contains ERC20 tokens for $ 1000, which the bot does not touch.

Prompt any script that can be run through geth to monitor the address and try to withdraw tokens or take the incoming ETH? - I have a private key!

I tried to try to start a transaction with the setInterval function at a time when there is zero in the wallet, so that when a payment arrives there, the transaction would occur, because it would be repeated all the time, but after 5 minutes it throws out the console from Geth, moreover, incoming payments are different all the time ...

What is the principle of the bot itself? Is he runing through Geth? Where is there a script for such a bot? The ether, by the way, is being transferred to different addresses all the time! But the bot monitors many of these addresses!

I understand that there are even a lot of bots that compete with each other!

Can you get something out of this? Or is it impossible?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand. Can you put an etherscan link to the account?

Comment: Try looking at the flashbots project, they have some tools for similar purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who has the private key can move funds out from the address. It does not matter where and how the bot is being run.

Comment: Yes, the key is already known by many people around the world... I think there is many bots are fightnig in the same time.

I jus want to know how i can try it too!

How can i run the same Bot? Where I can find it?

And why somebody send Eth to this adress?

And why the bots are disroying the Eth there?

I already know many another adresses with the same situation,,,